# promo_popup wont show in eval statment

Tags: magento2

So i wrote this piece of code, and it works if i remove the echo and outside php. But inside php, it wont show. I suspect it has something to do with "data-mage-init="{`promo_popup`:{}}". Anybody has an idea what to do or to solve it?

```
if($Popup_enable == 1){
echo '<div class="news-popup" data-mage-init="{`promo_popup`:{}}" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between no-gutters">
            <div class="col-11 col-md-9">
                <p>
                    <span class="alert-message d-inline-block font-weight-bold px-3 py-2">
                        '.$Popup_text.'
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    '.$Popup_b_text.'
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 col-md-auto text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-close inside-stroke-white-popup display-5">×</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fix like this

```
    echo '<div class="news-popup" id="news-popup" data-mage-init=\'{"promo_popup":{}}\' >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between no-gutters">
            <div class="col-11 col-md-9">
                <p>
                    <span class="alert-message d-inline-block font-weight-bold px-3 py-2">
                        '.$Popup_text.'
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    '.$Popup_b_text.'
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 col-md-auto text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-close inside-stroke-white-popup display-5">×</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Just put "" before "'"